# Efficient computation of inverse of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I want to efficiently compute the inverse of

$$T = RVD_1V^T F$$

where $D_1 \in \mathbb R^{k\times k}$ is a diagonal matrix, $V \in \mathbb R^{k\times k}$, $R \in \mathbb R^{n\times k}$, $F \in \mathbb R^{k\times n}$ and $k > n$.

Is it possible to write  $T$ or $VD_1V^T$ as the sum of diagonal and low-rank components? I think there is a way to write it, but I wasn't able to find it.

If I can write $T$ as $D + LL^T$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix, then I can efficiently take the inverse of $D + LL^T$ using [approximating diagonal of inverse sum of low rank and diagonal matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457719/approximating-diagonal-of-inverse-sum-of-low-rank-and-diagonal-matrices) or [Inverse of the sum of a invertible matrix with known Cholesky-decomposion and diagonal matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1747812/inverse-of-the-sum-of-a-invertible-matrix-with-known-cholesky-decomposion-and-di). Or is there any other method to efficiently compute the inverse of $T$?

Comment: Do you really need to compute the inverse? computing full inverse is not very efficient compared to the cost of solving a linear system of the form $Ax=b$.

Comment: @Surb Yes, I really need to compute the full inverse. I don't have linear system form.

Comment: do $V,R$ and $F$ have some structure?

Comment: @Surb No, they don't have same structure.

Comment: Is there a way to write $VD_1V^T$ as a sum of a diagonal matrix and low-rank matrix?